# Is it improper for the question asker to help the answerer revise the answer?

Tags: discussion

I've asked [[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619574/how-to-implement-a-dealer-class-without-storing-a-deck-of-cards)]

I have since revised the question into an analogy form, and the sample code in my post is so renamed. In order to avoid the previous answer being invalidated by my revision, I asked the author if I could edit his answer with the new method and class names.

I understand that editing a question and invalidating answers is bad, but in this case, I was helping the answer make sense with my recent question update. Why are some people considering rejecting or performing a rollback?

Comment: It's not really *that* important that the method/class names all be the same.  The answer isn't *invalid* because it has different names.  Some answerers even *choose* to use different names from posted example code, so while I may or may not reject such an edit, you certainly shouldn't feel obligated to ensure the answer is changed; it's okay as it is.

Comment: Side note, 35 revisions is *a lot*.  You should really trying taking more time to do fewer more substantial edits rather than constantly editing the post every few minutes.

Comment: It's worth noting that you didn't just rename some variables; you also re-ordered much of the content, added comments, and altered the whitespace formatting, making it look like a much more substantial code edit in the revision history.  It's rather hard to actually ensure that the code is identical; much harder than simply changing a variable name or two.

Comment: I'm not considering to revise more. Seriously change of the question would be seldom than frequently saving. I submit the edit frequently like I frequently press `Control-S` when I'm writing code.

Comment: And I'm telling you that you shouldn't be doing that.  If you need to be making period draft saves then copy the text into a text editor on your computer and copy it back up to the site when you're done.  It's disruptive to other readers to both flood the revision history and constantly bump the post when you're not actually done editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they don't know the whole story.

Write in the edit description that you're changing the class names and methods to match the newest edit in the question, it will be approved.

It's not "illegal" (very few things here are "illegal").